# Elixir-Phoenix: mix ecto.create and mix phx.server provoke same error but contain different postgres db parameters

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

When running `mix ecto.create` I get the following error:

```
17:47:14.118 [error] GenServer #PID<0.299.0> terminating
** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28000 (invalid_authorization_specification) no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.110.0.3", user "staging", database "postgres", SSL off
    (db_connection 2.4.0) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:100: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection 1.1.0) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib 3.15.2) proc_lib.erl:226: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol
```

Then, if I try to run `mix phx.server` I get the following error:

```
[error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.358.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28000 (invalid_authorization_specification) no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.110.0.3", user "staging", database "contact", SSL off
```

My database config in `dev.exs` is:

```
config :contact_api, ContactApi.Repo,
   username: System.get_env("DB_USER") || "postgres",
   password: System.get_env("DB_PWD")  || "postgres",
   database: System.get_env("DB_NAME") || "contact",
   hostname: System.get_env("DB_HOST") || "localhost",
   port: System.get_env("DB_PORT")     || "5432",
   show_sensitive_data_on_connection_error: true,
   pool_size: 10
```

- I have already checked that env variables are properly setter.
- I have also tried to test different env values but `mix ecto.create` still shows `postgres` for the database name at the error trace.
- I can connect to the database using `psql` from the same server as the app.
- When running a local DB with docker; `mix ecto.create`, `mix ecto.migrate`, `mix test`, and `mix phx.server` run as expected.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you remove the `System.get_env/1` entirely and use ONLY the hard-coded value?  This is just to check that a system variable isn't somehow being read differently in one case.

Comment: I can't claim to be any kind of expert on Postgres authentication, but from the web it looks like pg_hba.conf is a configuration file that is part of your Postgres database (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) that helps the system decide which authentication mechanism are allowed. Do you have such a file and does it contain values in-line with the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem. I am working with a cloud managed `postgres` database that is hosted by Digital Ocean. The only connections allowed are encrypted ones using `ssl certificates`. Error trace just informs about no user entry in `pg_hba.conf` but no reference to the ssl issue. Hence I had to modify `config/dev.exs`:

```
config :contact_api, ContactApi.Repo,
   username: System.get_env("DB_USER") || "postgres",
   password: System.get_env("DB_PWD")  || "postgres",
   database: System.get_env("DB_NAME") || "contact",
   hostname: System.get_env("DB_HOST") || "localhost",
   port: System.get_env("DB_PORT")     || "5432",
   show_sensitive_data_on_connection_error: true,
   pool_size: 10
   ssl: true,
   ssl_opts: [
     cacertfile: "cert/ca-certificate.crt"
   ]
```